# Windows Phone Tile push notification does not receive?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns, live-tile

Hi I am developing for Windows Phone 8. I need to send and receive tile push notification using PHP. The tile push notification is not received on my device. I am getting the error given below. Can anyone tell me why I am facing this issue?

Error:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-DeviceConnectionStatus: Connected X-NotificationStatus: Suppressed X-SubscriptionStatus: Active X-MessageID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ActivityId: d4a926a3-345c-432f-9a96-2f9c62ce8013 X-Server: DB3MPNSM036 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 09:08:33 GMT Content-Length: 0

I am using the code given below:

```
 HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "TileSampleChannel";
        InitializeComponent();
        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for Tile events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellTile();


        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
           // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        }





 void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Display the new URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
           // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", e.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        });
    }
    void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}",e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData)) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the [MPNS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941100%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) say about the response you got (200 OK, Suppressed, Connected, Active) :

> The push notification was received and dropped by the Push Notification Service. The Suppressed status can occur if the notification type was not enabled by calling BindToShellTile or BindToShellToast in the client application, if the raw notification was sent when the application was not in the foreground or if a Tile notification was sent with no Tile for the application pinned to start.

I see that you did call `BindToShellTile`, and you are not sending a raw notification, so perhaps the last option applies - `a Tile notification was sent with no Tile for the application pinned to start`.